# Explaining the number of solutions of a matrix (linear algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A be a m-by-n matrix and consider the system of linear equations $Ax=b$. We know that this system can either have no solution, exactly one solution or infinitely many solutions. Using linearity explain why this system cannot have exactly two solution.

What i attempted

I assume that the system have two solution and i assume that this is a system of three equations. So if we plot a graph of the 3 equations, all 3 lines must intersect at exactly 2 points. But we know that this is not possible no matter how we draw the lines, hence it is not possible for the system to have two equations. Is my explanation correct. Could anyone explain. Thanks

Comment: "Using linearity" does not mean "using lines" (in the geometric sense).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Suppose that we have two solutions $x_1 \neq x_2$ to the equation
$Ax = b$.

Using **linearity** (what is a *linear* transformation?), show that $\frac 12 (x_1 + x_2)$ is also a solution to this equation.

Answer (score 0):

If it has (at least) two solutions, it has an infinity of solutions:

To see this, let $x_1, x_2$ two distinct solutions, $t\in\mathbf R$. Then the set  $\{x\mid tx_1+(1-t)x_2\}$ is  the affine line defined by $x_1$  and $x_2$, and its vectors satisfy:
$$ Ax=A(tx_1+(1-t)x_2)=tAx_1+(1-t)Ax_2=tb+(1-t)b=b. $$